# Can I buy production facilities and/or houses from NPCs in Port Royale 1?

Tags: port-royale-gold-power-and-pirates

I have read that it is possible in other parts of the Port Royale series to do this, but is it also possible to do this in the first part? For example, instead of building production facilities and houses myself, I would like to buy them from NPCs in a city.

Can this be done **without** modding?